# Adding new handler to running python tornado server

Tags: python, tornado

I'm new to python tornado server, and I were evaluating python tornado for my next project that has to work on real time environment. I've run a sample code from github with Web Socket implementation.

this is the sample code snippet.

```
    app = web.Application([
       (r'/', IndexHandler),
       (r'/ws', SocketHandler),
       (r'/api', ApiHandler),
       (r'/(favicon.ico)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': '../'}),
       (r'/(rest_api_example.png)', web.StaticFileHandler, {'path': './'}),
   ])

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.listen(8080)
       ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

The code works as expected and fine.

Whether it is possible to give a cloud like solution so that I could **add new routes and handlers** dynamically to the web application without restarting the server listening a port.

For example; The server starts running and serves index.html for the route '/' and it has n viewers. If a new requirement came with route '/foo' to be served foo.html without blocking the n viewers of route '/'. What are the possible ways to handle without restarting the server, if any.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need the `tornado.web.Application`'s [`add_handlers`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.add_handlers) method; use it like this:

```
app.add_handlers(
    r".*",  # match any host
    [
        (
            r"/foo/([^/]*)",
            FooHandler
        ),
        (
            r"/bar/([^/]*)",
            BarHandler
        ),
    ]
)
```

Judging by its code, it does not block anything.