# How can I add websockets and handlers to a running tornado server?

Tags: websocket, request, addition, tornado, dynamically-generated

I'm trying to build a tornado application, where clients can register themselfes through a request to communicator websocket.

When the communicator receives a request to create a new handler and websocket should be added to the server. The new websocket is an intatiation of ClientWebSocketHandler.

How do I use function add_handlers() correctly.
How does the webserver get informed about new connections?
Any ideas what I'm missing here?
Is there a standard way for dynamically creatint more handlers and websockets?

```
class Communicator(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        print('communicator initialized')
    def open(self):
        print('communicator ready to receive messages')
    def on_message(self, msg):
        print('msg received: ' + msg)
        self.create_socket()
    def on_close(self):
        print('communicator closed')
    def create_socket(self):
        self.application.add_handlers(
        host_pattern = r'/',
        host_handlers = [
            (r'/clients/123', ClientWebsocketHandler),
        ]
    )

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
def __init__(self):
    settings = SWIFT_SERVER_SETTINGS
    handlers = [
        (r'/', IndexPageHandler),
        (r'/', tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, dict(path=settings['static_path'])),
        # (r'/clients/123', ClientWebsocketHandler),
        (r'/com', Communicator),
    ]
    tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)
```

Comment: I tried to follow this hint: [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802664/adding-new-handler-to-running-python-tornado-server 
But i doesn't seem to do anything to list of hosts and websockets.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need that function, change your code to this

```
clients=[]
class Communicator(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
         clients.append(self)
    def on_message(self, message):
          print self,message
          #return message
          self.write_message(message)
    def on_close(self):
          clients.remove(self)
```

I added clients objects to a global variable to later or in another function you can search for the object and write a message to that client.