# Add normal Tornado pages to Bokeh server application

Tags: bokeh

Can I serve normal HTML pages from a Bokeh server application?  Does doing this with Bokeh rather than Tornado add any additional costs?

I have a bokeh server running.  Mostly I use this for bokeh server pages.  However I also have a few other pages that I would like to make with more traditional HTML tools.  I know that I can create a Bokeh Application that just uses a template without any figures, but this seems like it might be overkill.  What are the costs to doing this?  Are there other options?  For example can I get at a lower-level Tornado HTTP server underneath and use that to host my normal pages on the same port?

Answer (score 1):

As of 0.12.10 the Bokeh server maintains a `tornado.web.application` on the `._torando` property.

```
>>> my_bokeh_server._tornado
<bokeh.server.tornado.BokehTornado at 0x7f104e7a0940>
```

As mentioned in [Adding new handler to running python tornado server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802664/adding-new-handler-to-running-python-tornado-server) you can add new RequestHandlers to a running Tornado Application

```
from tornado import web
class FooHandler(web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write('foo')

my_bokeh_server._tornado.add_handlers(r'.*', [
    ('/foo', FooHandler)
])
```

Comment: Please don't advocate for using private attributes. :) They may change at any time, without warning or deprecation.  If you are programmatically creating a `Server`, you can pass `extra_patterns` as seen here: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/tornado_embed.py#L47

Comment: Would you care to submit this as an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: I'd rather you just change this one