# How do I remove a route and its handler from a running tornado application

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I'm asking this because I can add routes and handlers to a tornado application while it is running thanks to this SO Question: [Adding new handler to running python tornado server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31802664/adding-new-handler-to-running-python-tornado-server)

I'm not seeing a `remove_handler` function or other way to remove existing routes while tornado is running. I'm guessing this simply isn't a use case that the tornado team thought was worth pursuing, and I can program around my issue. However, I'm not seeing SO questions or documentation and it seems odd that I can't reverse a modification to my web server. Any information or insight would be appreciated.

I'm using tornado 4.5, python 3.4 if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

If you see the [source code of `add_handlers`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/v5.1.1/tornado/web.py#L2045-L2060), you'll find that it inserts the given pattern and handler into a list called `Application.default_router.rules`. Which is basically a list containing routing [`Rules`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/routing.html#tornado.routing.Rule).

While I don't know why Tornado developers didn't provide any API to remove a handler, but I'm sure you can write some code to loop through all the rules inside `Application.default_router.rules` and remove whichever you want.